# How should I unit-test a class that relies on having realistic data?

Tags: unit-testing

I have a class that encapsulates the results of a scientific measurement. I’m building in unit tests from the beginning, but I don’t have a lot of experience with unit testing and I’m not sure which behaviors I should be testing and how.

My class does three kinds of things:

1. Reads measurement data from a file (or a string) into its instance variables
2. Writes its measurement data out to a file or a string
3. Performs calculations on its data (e.g. getting the average of a set of numbers)

My approach right now is to include a known-good example data file in my `test` directory. One test reads the data in from the file, passes it to my class, and makes sure that it meets some basic sanity checks. Another test passes the file’s *filename* to my class, lets the class read it, and runs the same tests. The remainder of the tests read the data in from the file, pass it to my class, and check that the results of the data-processing methods are correct, given what I know about that data set.

This seems pretty tangled, though. The tests that check (3) implicitly assume that the behaviors of (1) are correct, since it’s the functions in (1) that are being used to populate the class in the first place. And the tests of (1) could benefit from the extensive checks done by the tests for (3). Am I structuring my unit tests poorly, or is this just a natural result of the fact that I need to use a specific dataset in my tests?

Comment: Welcome to integration testing.  Seriously you are on the right track.  Some considerations: if you want it to look like your project is getting done fast, try big-bang integration.  If you want to be able to actually figure out what is wrong with your program, now **and** later, continue methodically establishing test cases for each subsystem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you're doing is integration testing, because as you can probably tell, your tests have dependencies on other parts of your code. This is fine, but it's good to know when you're looking at articles/examples/etc. online.

Some points to consider, and things to remember:

- **Arrange**, **Act**, **Assert**. All tests have these 3 steps.

  - Need more steps? You're probably testing too much for 1 test
  - No Arrange? You have external dependencies, which almost always makes tests flaky and unreliable.
  - Lots of Arrange code usually means lots of dependencies, and system-state types of dependencies. That's a recipe for fragile code.
  - No Act? Often tests the compiler. Leave that to compiler developers.
  - Lots of Act(s)? You're probably testing too much for 1 test again.
  - No Assert? Often the case when you want to test that "no errors occurred". No errors != working correctly.
  - Lots of Asserts? The code under test might be doing too much/touching too many systems. Try refactoring and testing the individual bits instead.
- Tests should exist on their own. Avoid scenarios where something that tests *3* depends on the code that does *1*. Instead, look to replace the code that does *1* with test code. In your scenario: try manually setting the values to what you want them to be in the test's **Arrange** step, then perform the **Act** ion (the calculations), then **Assert** the result.
- Happy-path tests are often a waste of time. Best-case scenarios almost always work. Your tests should be trying to force errors and edge cases.

  - Do you have a test that passes bad streams to be processed?
  - Do you have a test that passes null/non-existant filenames to be processed?
  - What happens if the numeric values to compute are not numeric, or when parsed are **huge**, or produce huge values when computed?
- Surprisingly writing tests rarely confirms that what you've done is right. Instead they give you insight into how usable, stable, and flexible your design is.

edit> This has already been accepted, but I wanted to add something that I learned long ago via [Pragmatic Unit Testing](http://pragprog.com/book/utc2/pragmatic-unit-testing-in-c-with-nunit):

*Unit Testing with your **Right BICEP***

- Are the results **Right** ?
- CORRECT **B** oundary Conditions

  - **C** onform to expected format
  - **O** rdered correctly
  - **R** ange is correct
  - **R** eferences to external dependencies are safe
  - **E** xistence (null etc.)
  - **C** ardinality
  - **T** iming (things happen in the right order, with the correct timing)
- **I** nverse relationships
- **C** ross-Check results with other means
- **E** rrors are forced
- **P** erformance characteristics are within acceptable bounds

Answer (score 5):

I think that your class is difficult to test because it has too many responsibilities. You mention them yourself

- Read data from file
- Write data to file
- Perform calculation

Ideally, a class should have a single responsibility, or a single area of responsibility. In this case, you should definitely have a class containing only the logic for performing the calculations.

If you had that, perhaps you could have a function like this:

```
CalculationResult PerformCalculation(Measurement[] measurements)
{ ... }
```

This becomes relatively easy to test, as you can easily supply a series of well defined measurements in a test.

I am assuming here that you read from the file once to get all measurements at once. If you collect new measurements written to the file over time, your class could look like this:

```
class Calculator {
    AddMeasurement(Measurement measurement) { ... }

    CalculationResult PerformCalculation() { ... }
}
```

Still easy to test, because you can feed the class with a series of well defined measurements during testing, and read the result, without having dependency to the file system.

A different class could have the responsibility of reading Measurement data from the file. This could again be split into reading data from a file, and parsing the data as Measurement objects, to allow testing the parsing logic separately without dependency to the file system, etc.

If it is difficult to write a unit test, this is often a sign that your "unit" has multiple responsibilities, too many dependencies, or in other ways are not [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

Answer (score 3):

Unit testing should test two sets of cases:

The very basic cases: is the calculation correct, do the totals add up, etc. Use simple easy to check data for these cases.

The edge cases: delivery date of Feb 29 2016, Order quantity of 999,999, Items with price $0.00, GPS for North Pole (try moving west!) etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think many of the answers are on point, in the sense that too many of the essential tests seem as though they are being combined into one unit test instance. BUT.

Many functions require complicated data and produce complicated results. Image processing, for example, may have a compact function which produces a mask from an image. A (I would argue, appropriate) test driver would read an image, process it, write an image file, and compare the resulting file to a reference image file.

Testing the integration in the target of all that functionality would be an integration test. Testing a single function of your target, a complicated input to a complicated output, is an appropriate unit test.